# Material Design - Page content exceeding screen width

Tags: width, material-design, limit, exceed

I'm having table content exceeding the screen width and I don't know how to fix it.

Tried to get `<class="md-layout__content">` or `<class="page-content">` maxwidth set to 100% of the current screen size but couldn't.

Also for left-padding the page content how should I proceed? I thought that I could add `<style="padding-left: %10">` or margin maybe?

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks :)

[Question Example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/79925719/question.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please removed following property from your style sheet for Table.
then this will solved your problem.

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

removed this property from `.mdl-data-table` class

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, I was unable to solve this with the `white-space: normal` attribute, but have also added `word-break: break-all; ` and I think it's working now :)

Comment: Sorry! I have now accepted it.
I have also tested that `word-wrap: break-word;` can also substitute `word-break: break-all` to solve this problem :)